# Multi-threaded Windows Service - Erlang

Tags: windows, erlang, latency, thrift, throughput

I am going to tell the problem that I have to solve and I need some suggestions if i am in the right path.

The problem is:

I need to create a Windows Service application that receive a request and do some action. (Socket communication) This action is to execute a script (maybe in lua or perl).This script models te bussiness rules of the client, querying in Databases, making request in websites and then send a response to the client.

There are 3 mandatory requirements:

1. The service will receive a lot of **request at the same time**. So I think to use the worker's thread model.
2. The service must have a high **throughput**. I will have many of requests at the same second.
3. **Low Latency**: I must response these requests very quickly.

Every request will generate a log entries. I cant write these log entries in the physical disk at same time the scripts execute because the big I/O time. Probably I will make a queue in memory and others threds will consume this queue and write on disk.

In the future, is possible that two woker's thread have to change messages.

I have to make a protocol to this service. I was thinking to use Thrift, but i don't know the overhead involved. Maybe i will make my own protocol.

To write the windows service, i was thinking in Erlang. Is it a good idea?

Does anyone have suggestions/hints to solve this problem? Which is the better language to write this service?

Comment: Without know what quantities "a lot", "high" and "very quickly" actually amount to, it's a bit of a subjective question.

Comment: @spender: yep, was ready to note this too, but then remembered that sometimes it's almost impossible to specify this even really roughly

Comment: Request per seconds: about 1k per second
Latency: about 600 ms. Depends the business rules that were implemented in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Erlang is a good choice if you're know it or ready to learn. With Erlang you don't need any worker thread, just implement your server in Erlang style and you'll receive multithreaded solution automatically.

Not sure how to convert Erlang program to Windows service, but probably it's doable.

Writing to the same log file from many threads are suboptimal because requires locking. It's better to have a log-entries queue (lock-free?) and a separate thread (Erlang process?) that writes them to the file. BTW, are you sure that executing external script in another language is much faster than writing a log-record to the file?

It's doubtfully you'll receive much better performance with your own serialization library than Thrift provides for free. Another option is [**Google Protocol Buffers**](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html), somebody claimed that it's faster.

Theoretically (!) it's possible that Erlang solution won't provide you required performance. In this case consider a compilable language, e.g. C++ and asynchronous networking, e.g. [**Boost.Asio**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html). But be ready that it's much more complicated than Erlang way.

Comment: The script will execute the customer business rules. After the scripts executes the customer wants to see the decisions made by the script. So thats why I need a log file. For the customers is better to write the log entry to a database because they can query online.

Does Erlang uses a pool of process to receive the request? Or it spawn a new process every time a request is made? Is it has a good performance? Can I implement the process pool?

Comment: 1) most probably your scripts will take much longer than your core logic, so your core performance won't be a bottleneck. 2) No need for process pool, Erlang uses light-weight processes, you can have millions of them with reasonable good performance. You just create ("spawn") process per client connection

Comment: But if i have a pool its not necessary to create a process. It just pick a process from the pool. The performance will be better. Am I right? thanks

Comment: you're right only if creation takes any significant amount of time. it's not true about Erlang processes

Comment: Run the Erlang emulator as a service on Windows --> http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlsrv.html